# Keras LSTM how to use the hidden state at each time step to change the input to the next timestep of the LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using `keras` to build an `LSTM` model. I want to manipulate the hidden state at each time step before feeding it back to the memory cell as a normal LSTM does. I am not sure if my implementation does this correctly. I am finding it hard to achieve this in keras.

What I am doing is looping over the number of time windows and feeding each input for a specific time window independently, that way I get the hidden state at that particular input only and after manipulation will be able to feed it back to the LSTM for the next time window input:

```
# initialize hidden state (encoder_state_h, encoder_state_c)
encoder = LSTM(units=units, return_state=True)

for i in range(config.time_window):
    # get only the input at this time step
    current_input = inputs[:, i, :]
    # do some manipulations to the current input which involves the hidden states

    output, encoder_state_h, encoder_state_c = encoder(current_input)
    
    # Saving each hidden state
    encoder_hidden_states.append(encoder_state_h)

# Stacking them as if normal lstm with return_sequence=True
encoder_hidden_states = tf.stack(encoder_hidden_states, axis=-1)
```

The manipulation done to each input consists of an Attention mechanism that should not be important to the current problem.

The issue is I am not sure if the implementation is correct. I am not feeding in the previous hidden state to the next time step (only the input). Keras does not look like it supports that as input.

**Is Keras automatically propagating the hidden state or is it resetting it every time I call `encoder`?**

I, essentially, want to have more control over the lstm at each time step which does not look like it is supported by Keras.

Any solution is welcome.